# 404 page not found with 3quarksdaily.com

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, blocked-services

I have been using the Tor browser bundle.  However the website http://www.3quarksdaily.com fails to load... it returns "404 page not found."

The website loads perfectly fine outside Tor.  I wonder what the problem is?  (I saw a similar post on htts://tor.stackexchange from last year but in that case the problem website was first presenting a captcha.  In this case there is no captcha, so perhaps the problem is different...)

Comment: The site presents me with a Captcha, so it's probably behind a Cloudflare firewall. Probably not much chance of getting to it. There are ongoing discussions about such things, including this blog entry: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/trouble-cloudflare

Answer (score 2):

The website http://www.3quarksdaily.com/ uses CloudFlare and CloudFlare has special [access rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967-How-do-I-control-access-to-my-site-). When they see a Tor exit relay the website operator can choose from [four options](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203306930-Does-CloudFlare-block-Tor-)

- let the traffic go through (whitelist)
- show a CAPTCHA
- show a JavaScript challenge or
- completely block the traffic.

It seems 3quarksdaily.com (or Typepad) has chosen to block Tor traffic.

You can try to use the service of [archive.is](https://archive.is/) to save and browse the page. I tried to access it via https://archive.is/ewEJl.
Furthermore you can write a mail to support@typepad.com and ask them to unblock Tor connections. If you decide for this variant it would be nice to comment and tell us what they answered.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the editor of 3quarksdaily.com and he emailed Typepad to investigate.  Unfortunately Typepad is blocking Tor.  Here is the response from Typepad:

> Due to an increase in spamming and abuse from users of the Tor
>   anonymous proxy, it was necessary to block access to Typepad sites from
>   Tor users. We hope you understand the need for this level of security
>   to project you and other members of the Typepad community.
>
> For visitors to your site who prefer to use Tor, we would suggest that
>   they subscribe to the blog's feed using a feed or subscribe to receive
>   updates to your blog via email.
>
> If you have any other questions or concerns, please let us know.
>
> Jen

Comment: Thanks for asking and posting the answer here. However I tried to acces http://3quarksdaily.blogs.com/3quarksdaily/index.rdf (RSS) using Tor and also get a 404 page. So subscribing to the feed by using Tor will not work.